# How to deal with @ symbol in password - sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to connect to a database in postgresql from my flask application but am  being hit with message below in the browser

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "flask_admin"
FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "flask_admin"
 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
```

I have set my environment variable `DATABASE_URL` to what is below this statement

```
postgresql://flask_admin:example@dev@18@localhost/flask_dev
```

And here is the code in my `config.py`

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))


class Config:

    DEBUG = False
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or \
        '\xfe\xccT\nn\x80\xe3\xfd\xc6\xf8\xd6\xab\xd8\x82\xc2\x1f'
    SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN = True
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False

    @staticmethod
    def init_app(app):
        pass


class DevelopmentConfig(Config):

    DEBUG = True
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'test.db')


class ProductionConfig(Config):

    DEBUG = False
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL') or \
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'test.db')


config = {
    'development': DevelopmentConfig,
    # 'testing': TestingConfig,
    'production': ProductionConfig,
    'default': DevelopmentConfig
}
```

My biggest guess is that the error is being caused by the `@` symbol in the password and am quite certain my password is correct.

How do i go about solving this issue because information given in the [link](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/errors.html#error-e3q8) provided in the error message is quite vague?

Here are my pg_hba.conf settings?

```
# PostgreSQL Client Authentication Configuration File
# ===================================================
#
# Refer to the "Client Authentication" section in the PostgreSQL
# documentation for a complete description of this file.  A short
# synopsis follows.
#
# This file controls: which hosts are allowed to connect, how clients
# are authenticated, which PostgreSQL user names they can use, which
# databases they can access.  Records take one of these forms:
#
# local      DATABASE  USER  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# host       DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostssl    DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
# hostnossl  DATABASE  USER  ADDRESS  METHOD  [OPTIONS]
#
# (The uppercase items must be replaced by actual values.)
#
# The first field is the connection type: "local" is a Unix-domain
# socket, "host" is either a plain or SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket,
# "hostssl" is an SSL-encrypted TCP/IP socket, and "hostnossl" is a
# plain TCP/IP socket.
#
# DATABASE can be "all", "sameuser", "samerole", "replication", a
# database name, or a comma-separated list thereof. The "all"
# keyword does not match "replication". Access to replication
# must be enabled in a separate record (see example below).
#
# USER can be "all", a user name, a group name prefixed with "+", or a
# comma-separated list thereof.  In both the DATABASE and USER fields
# you can also write a file name prefixed with "@" to include names
# from a separate file.
#
# ADDRESS specifies the set of hosts the record matches.  It can be a
# host name, or it is made up of an IP address and a CIDR mask that is
# an integer (betweenand(IPv4) or(IPv6) inclusive) that
# specifies the number of significant bits in the mask.  A host name
# that starts with a dot (.) matches a suffix of the actual host name.
# Alternatively, you can write an IP address and netmask in separate
# columns to specify the set of hosts.  Instead of a CIDR-address, you
# can write "samehost" to match any of the server's own IP addresses,
# or "samenet" to match any address in any subnet that the server is
# directly connected to.
#
# METHOD can be "trust", "reject", "md5", "password", "gss", "sspi",
# "ident", "peer", "pam", "ldap", "radius" or "cert".  Note that
# "password" sends passwords in clear text; "md5" is preferred since
# it sends encrypted passwords.
#
# OPTIONS are a set of options for the authentication in the format
# NAME=VALUE.  The available options depend on the different
# authentication methods -- refer to the "Client Authentication"
# section in the documentation for a list of which options are
# available for which authentication methods.
#
# Database and user names containing spaces, commas, quotes and other
# special characters must be quoted.  Quoting one of the keywords
# "all", "sameuser", "samerole" or "replication" makes the name lose
# its special character, and just match a database or username with
# that name.
#
# This file is read on server startup and when the postmaster receives
# a SIGHUP signal.  If you edit the file on a running system, you have
# to SIGHUP the postmaster for the changes to take effect.  You can
# use "pg_ctl reload" to do that.

# Put your actual configuration here
# ----------------------------------
#
# If you want to allow non-local connections, you need to add more
# "host" records.  In that case you will also need to make PostgreSQL
# listen on a non-local interface via the listen_addresses
# configuration parameter, or via the -i or -h command line switches.

# DO NOT DISABLE!
# If you change this first entry you will need to make sure that the
# database superuser can access the database using some other method.
# Noninteractive access to all databases is required during automatic
# maintenance (custom daily cronjobs, replication, and similar tasks).
#
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
#local   replication     postgres                                peer
#host    replication     postgres        127.0.0.1/32            md5
#host    replication     postgres        ::1/128                 md5
```

Comment: Escape the @, use \@ instead?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher it is still not working and the error is still the same

Comment: What happens if you use percent encoding? So replace the ‘@‘ with ‘%40’.

Comment: @rfkortekaas it is also not working

Comment: How does your connection URI looks like after the change?

Comment: Can you also post the pg_hba.conf file? Maybe password authentication is not allowed at the moment!

Comment: @rfkortekaas i have added the `pg_hba.conf` file contents

Comment: Percent encoding should've worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1423804/writing-a-connection-string-when-password-contains-special-characters, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15728290/sqlalchemy-valueerror-for-slash-in-password-for-create-engine

Comment: What happens if you change peer on the ‘local all all’ line to md5 or add an entry with ‘host all all localhost md5’?

Comment: @rfkortekaas thank you, it works

Answer (score 11):

special characters in the password need to be URL encoded to be parsed correctly as mentioned in the [sqlalchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/engines.html#database-urls).

```
import urllib.parse
urllib.parse.quote_plus("kx%jj5/g")
>>>'kx%25jj5%2Fg'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @rfkortekaas help after changing the content in my `/etc/postgresql/9.x/main/pg_hba.conf` file on this line

```
# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
```

to

```
local   all             all                                     md5
```

After which i ran the following commands

```
sudo service postgresql restart
sudo -u postgres psql
ALTER USER flask_admin WITH PASSWORD 'example@dev@18';
```

Everything seems to work fine now.

**ALL CREDIT TO** @rfkortekaas